# How to find a button within <ul> and <li> via Proctractor?

Tags: protractor

I am new to automation, and my previous experiences were with non-Angular apps, thus i start to use Protractor.

I want to navigate throught the website, though cannot find the right selector.

[The button is highlighted in red on the bottom of the screen:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4OqU.png)

I've tried below code among many:

`element(by.name('Flota')).click()`

or

```
element(by.css('.ng-tns-c11-5')).click()
element(by.css('div[title=Flota]'));
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should target the `<a>` or `<nb-icon>` element instead?
Try the following locators:

**using a:**

```
element(by.css('.ng-tns-c11-16.ng-star-inserted.active'));
```

**or nb-icon**:

```
element(by.css('.menu-icon.ng-tns-c11-16.ng-star-inserted'));
```

Additionally, if you need to target the `<span>` element:

```
element(by.css('.ng-tns-c11-16.ng-star-inserted.active span'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

`by.css("a[title='Flota']") //if this is the button you are looking for`

Since the shorter is locator - the better

Answer (score -1):

your help was much appreciated!

Unfortunately, i tried all options you provided and didn't work, though i made additional trial and error runs. 
The code i worked out is below, maybe it will help another newbie like me:

element.all(by.css('#menu-item ng-tns-c11-4 ng-star-inserted li')).click()